# pscustomobject: delete unique, keep duplicates

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, pscustomobject

I have written a script that extracts all the duplicate emails in a WS2012 AD.

The Script has all the Users with duplicate emails in a `pscustomobject`

Now what i want to achieve is to delete the first unique email entry and keep all the duplicate email entries so i can build dummy emails for the duplicate ones, leaving the first unique email entry alone so every user in the AD can have a unique email even if it is a dummy email.

This is an example of what the `pscustomobject` exported into CSV looks like:

```
Name     Telephone    Email     Department

Max Smith 12345 max@gmail.com Billing
Max Jones 6789 max@gmail.com Facility
James Adams 52585 james@outlook.com Import
James Jones 46844 james@outlook.com Service
James Bones 68315 james@outlook.com Management
```

What i need to build out of the above is:

```
Name     Telephone    Email     Department

Max Jones 6789 max@gmail.com Facility
James Jones 46844 james@outlook.com Service
James Bones 68315 james@outlook.com Management
```

The first email entry is gone, all the duplicates are still there.

The dummy email would be telephoneNumber@company.com like `46844@microsoft.com` for James Jones.

I am constantly failing to build a `pscustomobject` without the first unique email and consisting of duplicates only.

I hope the Wizards of Stack Overflow can help me.

Thank You and Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to only "keep the duplicates", you need to keep track of email addresses you've already seen before.

For this, I'd recommend using a `HashSet<string>` - a set only contains distinct values, and is *very fast* at determining whether a given value is already a member of the set in the first place - ideal for this use case.

*In the following, I assume that `$data` contains an array of `pscustomobject`s as described in the question*:

```
$alreadySeen = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()

$duplicatesOnly = $data |Where-Object { -not $alreadySeen.Add($_.Email) }

$duplicatesOnly |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv
```

The first time you add a unique value to the set, `Add()` will return `$true`, but subsequent attempts to add the same value will return `$false` - meaning our `Where-Object` filter will only filter through objects where the `Email` column has already been seen at least once before.

If the emails are not uniformly cased, supply a case-insensitive string comparer when creating the hashset:

```
$alreadySeen = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I tried your method. It does work but is case sensitive. Duplicates like `Max.Jones@gmail.com` and `max.jones@gmail.com` are not being recognized as duplicates. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: @Zombievirus Yes, that's easily addressed, I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank You Mathias. I tested it and my Problem is solved. I upvoted your answer. Thank You very much again :)